# verilog: a genvar 'i' following with width?

Tags: verilog

```
module xxx
(
    input   wire    [`NUM+7:0]  dec_in,
    output  wire    [`NUM-1:0]  dec
);

generate
genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < `NUM; i=i+1) begin : 
        assign base = (dec_of_onehot >= i[`NUM-1:0]);
        assign bound = (dec_of_onehot <= i[`NUM-1:0]);
        assign onehot_of_dec[i]  = (base == 1'b1) && (bound == 1'b1);
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

What's the meaning of assign xxx?
Does not contain variable definitions for base and bound but still works.
and a genvar 'i' following with width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base` and `bound` are implicit 1-bit wire declarations for each iteration of the generate loop. Unless you name the `begin/end` generate block, they are local to each block.

I assume there must be variable declarations for the other variables that you did not show.

BTW, relying on implicit wire declarations is poor programming practice. It would be much clear to show the intent

```
genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < `NUM; i=i+1) begin
        wire base, bound;
        assign base = (dec_of_onehot >= i[`NUM-1:0]);
        assign bound = (dec_of_onehot <= i[`NUM-1:0]);
        assign onehot_of_dec[i]  = (base == 1'b1) && (bound == 1'b1);
    end
```

Comment: The code surely doesn't have variable declarations of 'base' and 'bound'. but it still compiled success and IMPLEMENTATION to the right circuit. probably because of ' implicit wire declarations'. thks